# Linked List memory issue

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linked-list, valgrind, heap-memory

I'm actually working on a project about the manipulation of linked lists and everything works perfectly, but when i run it with valgrind i see that there are  a lot of memory issues. I'm putting here a part of the code, where i think the problem of memory allocated is so maybe you can help me to find it out.

So, i have to read from a file of this format:

```
19971230 20220512 ALklklklk
19970905 20001203 BDHE UNE
20151212 20301123 CLEUSHI
20171221 20301025 DE klkllLU TOPI
20160315 20190227 Ehaaaa
```

and put them in a linked list, represented by this strucuture:

```
typedef struct cell{
    int dateDeb;
    int dateFin;
    char text[TAILLE_MAX];
    struct cell * suivant;
}message;
```

In the beginning i have coded this function to initialize a block of the list:

```
message * creationCellule(){

    message * cellule;
    cellule = (message *)malloc(sizeof(message));

    if(cellule != NULL)
    {
        cellule -> dateDeb = 0;
        cellule -> dateFin = 0;
        cellule -> suivant = NULL;
        memset(cellule->text, '\0', TAILLE_MAX);
    }
    return cellule;

}
```

And the function to read from the file is this one:

```
void lectureFichier(const char * nomFichier, message ** tete)
{


    FILE * fp = fopen(nomFichier, "r");
    message * test;
    test = creationCellule();

    if(fp != NULL)
    {

        while(fscanf(fp,"%d %d ", &(test->dateDeb), &(test->dateFin)) == 2)
        { 
            fgets(test -> text, 100, fp);

            insertion(tete, test);
            test =  creationCellule(test);

        }
    }
    fclose(fp);                                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

The insertion function is this one:

```
void insertion(message ** tete, message * cellule){

    message ** prec;


    if(cellule != NULL){
            prec = recherche(tete, cellule -> dateDeb);
            cellule -> suivant = *prec;
            *prec = cellule;
    }

}
```

Valgrind tells me that there is a memory leak and the dynamic allocated memory is not freed. And it's right because i don't free anything in these  functions, but i don't know where to use free because i have to reuse it inside the loop. Here's the valgrind result:

[image]

Can you please show me a solution how to solve this issue because i'm stuck in this. Even if i need to the function creationCellule, it's OK. It's not obligated to write that one. Thank you so much in advance !

Comment: It leaks memory because you're not constructing your *linked list*. You're supposed to assign the *first* `test` to `*tete` and then link the following elements to each other

Comment: @AnttiHaapala yes i'm constructing it with insertion function.I do it with insertion.

Comment: Then the insertion function is wrong, but you forgot to include it into the question.

Comment: Ok i will add it right now so you can check if you can. Thank you

Comment: Ahha but now I see it: where do you actually insert the *last* created cellule?

Comment: A simple fix would be to `free(test)` next to the `fclose`.

Comment: You're right i don't insert it anywhere, but i added free() after the while right now and it still doesn't work.

Comment: i think i have a problem with creationCellule , because i don't know how to free the cell that i allocate there. Don't you think ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in link list creation. However, once you are done with reading file and link list you need to free up. Remember if you used malloc(), you have to call free() to free up the memory. Something like this - freeCellule(), you can call this function before returning from lectureFichier():

```
   void freeCellule(message *ptr)
   {
       message * next;
       while (ptr) {
           next = ptr->suivant;
           free(ptr);
           ptr = next;

      }
   }
```

Comment: thank you, i've used this is in main but it doesn't work neither.